# What are the possible values of regconfig in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-controls.html often refers to an optional **regconfig** parameter, but I can't find its possible values and their meanings. Where is it documented? If this can't be answered (e.g. because it depends on my installed database-components or like), how can I determine it myself?
2. I'd like a "plain text" regconfig, without any human-language transformation. What is the argument for it?

Comment: Checked over here? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-configuration.html

Comment: Well... Not really. It doesn't answer the question, I'm afraid.
The only little reference to the list of text search configurations is the "\dF" command or option. The "=>" looks like a command prompt, but I can't imagine what program it belongs to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it and the remaining chapters of the manual actually do, if you go through the examples. (Basically: regconfig is one of the configs you registered, if any, on top of the built-in ones, i.e. english. It's not just a simple string, either: if you browse through the catalog's various tables, you'll find plenty of related tables.) The prompt at the very end of the page is that of the `psql` utility.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. `psql` listed me the text search configurations.
(The prompt was `postgres=#` for me.)

Answer (score 4):

A `text search configuration` is a grouping of configuration objects: *parsers, templates,* and *dictionaries*. As far as I can tell the only configuration choices built-in are the language-specific ones like 'english' or 'finnish'.

You can see a list of configurations in your database via the `\dF` command in the `psql` command line tool, or via a query:
`select * from pg_catalog.pg_ts_config;`

Regarding a "plain text" configuration (#2), I'm not sure what you need but look at creating a custom dictionary. Perhaps start with the built-in "simple" dictionary and remove the stop words?
`COMMENT ON TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY simple IS 'simple dictionary: just lower case and check for stopword';`

Reference: [Configurations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS)

Answer (score 1):

The blog article [Mastering PostgreSQL Tools: Full-Text Search and Phrase Search](https://www.compose.com/articles/mastering-postgresql-tools-full-text-search-and-phrase-search/) answers your question in full.

To summarize:

The `regconfig` is the Search Configuration object which is, itself, a collection of templates, parser dictionaries and stopwords. You can find it using the command `\dF`. To find out more about a particular `regconfig`, such as english/dutch use the command `\dF+ dutch`

For setting up own `regconfig`, you'll need access to the `postgres.conf` file, which isn't always allowed.